# The type org.apache.xmlrpc.common.XmlRpcHttpRequestConfigImpl cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, xml-rpc

I have physically copy xmlrpc-client-3.1.3.jar to./lib,then right click on it to select "Build Path>Add Path".

On Menu Bar,select Project >Properties>Java Build Path.

On "Libraries" tab ,xmlrpc-client-3.1.3.jar found and 
"Order and Export" tab has checked on xmlrpc-client-3.1.3.jar-XXX/lib

By the time,I code as below

```
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient;
import org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClientConfigImpl;

public class someClass{

....
XmlRpcClientConfigImpl config = new XmlRpcClientConfigImpl();
config.setServerURL(new URL("http://somedomain.com/index.php/api/xmlrpc/"));
}
```

I get the error

- The type org.apache.xmlrpc.common.XmlRpcHttpRequestConfigImpl cannot 
  be resolved. It is indirectly   referenced from required .class files

I use eclipse on project development

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue but now I have managed to resolve it. Your just missing the xmlrpc client common jar file.

Just download the following package

> xmlrpc-client-common-3.1.3.jar

Add it to your project using same procedures you did for adding xmlrpc-client-3.1.3.jar

CHEERS

Answer (score 1):

And you can [download it here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlrpc/xmlrpc-common/3.1.3). Using xmlrpc client jar alone will give you error; so just download the xmlrpc common, add jar as external, clean your project and your ready to go. happy codings,

-cheers